# Use the result of ToLower() as parameter

Tags: powershell

I try something like this to use the lowercase computer name in an argument list but what I get instead is the text `COMPUTER.ToLower()`

With this code:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "path to exe" -ArgumentLlist "-n $Env:ComputerName.ToLower()"
```

How do I get instead the text `computer` used in the argument list?

Comment: Use the `$()` subexpression operator: `"-n $($Env:ComputerName.ToLower())"`

Comment: If you don't need any `Start-Process` features: `& "path to exe" -n $Env:ComputerName.ToLower()`. PowerShell adds quotes as necessary.